# How to make a N-level tree in pyramid fashion, such that each child may(doesn't mean has to) have 2 parents?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

The question may look very simple, and probably the answer is too, but I always get confused in the tree questions. 
Ok so I want to make a tree something like:

```
         3     level 0 
        / \ 
       4   5   level 1 ..
      / \ / \
     6   7   8
    / \ / \ / \
   9   10  11  12
```

What are such trees called? Sorry, I'm a beginner..
Function can pass an array[] of ints, or function can take input till N = 3 (denoting level 3 with 10 nodes). Also can you give solution in C/C++/Java.

Comment: Wikipedia: A full binary tree (sometimes 2-tree or strictly binary tree) is a tree in which every node other than the leaves has two children. A full tree is sometimes ambiguously defined as a perfect tree. Physicists define a binary tree to mean a full binary tree.

Comment: And what you have drawn is not even a tree with all those circular sub-graphs

Comment: @Martin Can u suggest me a DS to store the above then?

Comment: It's hard to give any sensible advice without knowing how the data structure will be used. Will it change dynamically in runtime? What operations would you like to be able to perform on it?

Comment: @Martin it will not change on runtime. I would like to traverse through it like left, right. thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your requirements are only for traversal, I would simply implement this using an array `a`, containing each level as a contiguous sub-array. Level `i` then occurs in entries `L(i-1)` up to but not including `L(i)`, where `L(n) = n*(n+1)/2`. In particular, the `j`th value on the `i`th level is in `a[L(i-1)+j]`.

As long as you always keep track of `i` and `j`, you can now easily navigate through your pyramid.

Comment: I worked it as a 2D array, but thanks :) with children of node(r,c) = node(r+1, c) and node(r+1,c+1). Also if u don't want to waste space, I used array of pointers and dynamically allocated memory to it